# Finding column creation time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I wonder if is it possible to get creation date of column in a table? I want to see the creation times of columns that added later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you can get this information for the table quite easily. You would query the information_schema for the create_time of the table.

For instance:

```
SELECT create_time FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
  AND table_name = 'your_table'
```

Check here for more information:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html

For a specific column this is not as simple because none of the system tables (that is, nothing in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database) exist that has that kind of information recorded anywhere. In other words, there is no native mechanism to put any timestamps on column changes.

Any time that:

1. one or more columns change in any row
2. a new row is added
3. an old is deleted
4. an ALTER TABLE of any kind

the UPDATE_TIME column in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES is updated.

You could find all changes in the last hour (or your selected interval) quite simply though:

```
SELECT CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME) AS Table, UPDATE_TIME AS Updated
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) < UPDATE_TIME
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA != 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
  AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for information, it didn't help. Because i really want to know exactly when did column is create. Thanks.